# automatic change text into other language + google translator

Tags: php, google-translate

In my PHP application there a new functionality I have to develop that is when user fill sign in form(html),whatever he/she put in "Name" field other two fileds i.e. "name in traditional Chinese" and "name in Chinese" should automatically filled.
I want to know is it possible with google translator? if yes then please share with me code or example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want the translations perfomed on the server side (PHP) you can use file_get_contents to fetch data from Google Translate API. Then you need to parse the response and get translated text. You need to get [API KEY](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) to access the Translate service.

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello World';
$source_lang = 'en';
$target_lang = 'zh-CN'

header ( "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8" );
$data = file_get_contents ( 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q='.urlencode($string).'&source='.$source_lang.'&target='.$target_lang ); 
$data = json_decode ( $data );  
$translated = $data->data->translations->[0]->translatedText;
echo $translated;

?>
```

Server responses are JSON objects with that structure:

```
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "translatedText": "Hallo Welt",
                "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

More info about basic concept is avaliable on: 
http://baris.aydinoglu.info/coding/google-translate-api-in-php.

Documentation of Google Translate API queries:
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to apply http://baris.aydinoglu.info/coding/google-translate-api-in-php solution, but in this the very first link http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=hola%20mundo&langpair=es|en , giving some sort of error, can you please help me what is this?

Comment: The site uses version 1 of the API. It was deprecated in favor of v2 http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks again, your answer helped me a lot, +1 for this, I have created new api key and use your code, but it giving me error  
" "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"

Comment: I think the Translation API is a paid service now and there is a daily limit of queries.

Comment: ohhh.. so is there any other method? you can suggest me?

Comment: What about [Microsoft Translator V2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512407.aspx). The usage seems to be quite similiar to Google's, only with different URL and response format. Unfortunately i don't have the AppId to test it.